# AES key has a LF character in it

Tags: terminal, openssl, aes, newline, cbc-mode

I am trying to decrypt a video file using openssl. But 16 byte aes key has a line feed (LF) character in it.

```
x
yÏï:YÛI?þbl
```

Because of the LF, when I copy the key to the terminal, it sends only "x" not the whole key.

How can I type this key on terminal?

> openssl aes-128-cbc -d -in input.ts -out output.ts -pass [aes_key]

Comment: You, uh, probably don't want to be typing that at all... anyway, try putting it a file and then ``-pass `cat (file)` ``. Or maybe it expects the file, judging from the description, "pass phrase source": `-pass (file)`. And that doesn't look like a passphrase, so maybe you were looking for the `-K` option instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try parameter -K

from openssl help:

```
-K/-iv         key/iv in hex is the next argument
```

So something like this should work

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -d -in input.ts -out output.ts -K 00EF45....
```

where 00EF45.... will be your aes key in hexadecimal format.